# Trouble checking out remote branch in git

Tags: git, version-control

I currently am having trouble using `git fetch`; `git checkout branch-name` to check out a remote branch in git. I get the error `fatal: 'origin/makeathon-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'makeathon-branch' cannot be created from it`. When I run `git ls-remote --heads origin`, I see the remote branch in the list, but then I try to check out that branch and get the error. The only remote branches that show are `origin/master` and `origin/HEAD`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `git fetch --all` change anything?

Comment: unfortunately no @Jonathan.Brink

Comment: What do you get from running `git rev-parse origin/makeathon-branch` and from `git cat-file -t origin/makeathon-branch`? The first should be a hash ID and the second should be the word `commit`; if either one fails or isn't right, that explains why `git checkout` fails, and we're probably looking at your `remote.origin.fetch` setting.

Comment: @torek I get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/makeathon-branch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: So yeah, it looks like there's an issue with the fetch

Comment: OK, so, what does `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` show? It should (normally) be `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, but if you originally cloned with `--single-branch`, it won't be and you will have to re-set it to that.

Comment: So I have two: `refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` and 
`refs/heads/graphql:refs/remotes/origin/graphql`. But overall it looks correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per comments, the output of:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

is:

```
refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
refs/heads/graphql:refs/remotes/origin/graphql
```

(without leading plus signs).

This tells you Git that when you run `git fetch origin`, it should:

- Look at their (origin's) `master` branch: if you don't have an `origin/master` remote-tracking name, create it; or if your `origin/master` is strictly behind their `master` branch, fast-forward your `origin/master` to match their `master`.

If your `origin/master` disagrees with their `origin/master` in any other way, refuse to update your `origin/master` (as such an update is not a fast-forward).  This should almost never happen, and if it does happen, it means someone force-pushed to origin; but in general, if someone *did* force-push to origin, you probably should pick up the new value.

To make that happen, the refspec—this pair of names with a colon between them—should start with a leading plus sign `+`.

- Look at their `graphql` branch: if you don't have that, or it's behind, do the appropriate creation or fast-forward.  As before, if your remote-tracking name disagrees in some other way (is ahead of, or both ahead and behind, their branch), refuse to update it.
- Discard all their other branch information: you don't care about any other branches.

Clearly, this last bullet point is wrong, because there is one more branch of theirs that you *do* care about now, namely their `makeathon-branch`.

You can change all of this in one swell foop,<sup>1</sup> by changing this to the standard setting:

```
git remote set-branches origin '*'
```

(this requires your Git version be at least 1.7.2), or:

```
git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

(the quotes are to protect the `*` characters from the shell and are not required with some Windows shells, and only sometimes required with sh/bash).  This standard setting means:

- Look at all of origin's branches.  For each one, forcibly create or re-set your corresponding remote-tracking name so that it matches theirs.

This will create the name if it is new, fast-forward it if it exists and is behind, or re-set it if it exists and disagrees with theirs.

Alternatively, if you wish to retain only the three remote-tracking names so far, you can add `refs/heads/makeathon-branch:refs/remotes/origin/makeathon-branch`, with a leading plus sign if you want to pick up all updates, or without it if you only want to pick up new creations and fast-forwards.

There are additional ways to adjust your configuration, including my personal favorite of just using `git config --edit` to invoke your usual editor on the configuration file (but make sure that whatever editor you use saves the file as plain-text).

---

<sup>1</sup>A [spoonerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) of [fell swoop](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71769/what-is-the-origin-of-in-one-fell-swoop).

Comment: Not sure if it changed at some point, but in recent git (2.26.2), the `git remote` command is `git remote set-branches origin '*'` (i.e. no hyphens)

Comment: @ncoghlan: Oops, no, I just typo-ed (well, "brain-o" rather than typo) the whole thing. Will fix. (I put in the erroneous `--set-branches` while simplifying the answer in an earlier edit.)

Comment: No worries. This answer helped solve an utterly baffling behaviour in BitBucket CI (turns out BB's default pulls on tags set a very restrictive remote branch filter, so fetching other branches doesn't work right unless you reset the mask first)